# Yii2 kartik-v ExportMenu

Tags: kartik-v

I have installed this [particular plugin](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-export) for Yii2 and unfortunately, I receive the following error

[image]

My composer version is 1.8.4, composer.json (require section)

```
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "slavkovrn/yii2-lightbox": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev"
```

and of course php version

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem by updating composer php path to version 7.1 instead of 5.5.12 that was set by default.

Regards